# Square root of a 100 digit number in C++

Tags: c++, square-root

*'unsigned long long'* can solve upto 15 digits.

Is there a way to find square-root of a ***100 digit number***?

Comment: I know this is probably not what you're looking for, but in case you don't need an exact result, you can just use `double`.

Comment: @Detheroc that would be a good first step to compute the real value with an algorithm like the newton method.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use *Boost.Multiprecision* library. This library provides wrappers for some popular multiprecision implementations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

#include <boost/multiprecision/mpfr.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string s(100, '0');
    s.at(0) = '1';
    boost::multiprecision::mpfr_float_100 f(std::move(s));
    boost::multiprecision::mpfr_float_100 sqrt = boost::multiprecision::sqrt(f);
    std::cout << sqrt.str() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Definitely.  One easy way would be to use the GNU multi-precision library's [mpz_sqrt()](http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Roots.html#Integer-Roots) function.

Answer (score 3):

This question isnt really related to C++, but here is a list of methods you can use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots

Depending on if its homework or not you might be able to use a premade lib to handle bignums