# Using sqrt function in c++

Tags: c++

So, I am using `sqrt` function in c++ and the problem I am facing is, when the input to `sqrt` is `40000000001`, it returns 200000.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    long long int a;
    cin>>a;
    double b = sqrt(a);
    cout<<b<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this happening?

It should return 200000.0000025 and I need this exact value. Even getting 200000 produces a Wrong answer. Thanks!

Comment: `std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << '\n';`. Something tells me you're going to get a value considerably lower than 40000000001. Something on the order of `2147483647` likely.

Comment: ...and what is the size of your `int`?

Comment: 4-billion-and-1 is too big to fit in a 32-bit unsigned `int` (the most common size). Why don't you make `a` a `double` too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Guaranteed precision of sqrt function in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259537/guaranteed-precision-of-sqrt-function-in-c-c)

Comment: @TonyD that's not 4-billion, it's *40*-billion, but your point is still completely valid.

Comment: The maxint issue would have been revelaed if you had used a debugger, or even printed out the int.

Comment: Squaring 46341 gives 2147488281, a number suspiciously similar to that prophecised by @WhozCraig

Comment: It's not result that is wrong, it is only the display of the result that cuts off the digits after the comma. You can check in a debugger or by adjusting the precision of the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

adding a

```
cout << "a=" << a << endl;
```

will reveal that when you enter `40000000001` the value of `a` is actually 46341. This is because to represent 40000000001 in an int you'll need 36 bits, while on your platform, int most likely only has 32 bits (31 plus one sign).

Using a `long` instead, I get `200000` as a result. <strike>The fact that you don't get 200000.0000025 must have to do with the fact that also doubles only have a limited amount of precision. Even though [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) says that a 64 bit double has a precision of typically 15-17 decimal digits and the number you are looking for has 13 significant digits, I suspect there are roundoff errors in the intermediate steps of the calculation.</strike>

---

Part of the problem is also the printing, if you print for example:

```
    cout << b - 200000 << endl;
```

then I get

```
    2.49999e-06
```

as output which is very close to 0.0000025 . You can increase the number of digits which are printed:

```
    cout << setprecision(13) << b << endl;
```

which then prints `200000.0000025` on my platform.

---

If you need more precision than the primitive types provide, there are libraries to do that, see e.g. [this list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software). In particular, boost seems to have a library for that and here is an example taking a square root of a 100 digit number: [Square root of a 100 digit number in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998332/square-root-of-a-100-digit-number-in-c)

Comment: @DanAllen why would the *compiler* generate a warning about a value that isn't even known until *runtime*?

Comment: If I want it to be exact as 200000.0000025, what should I do?

Comment: @WhozCraig, how can I get the exact value then?

Comment: @Elliot - you understand that 'exact' and 'floating point handling on computers' are rarely found in the same context?

Comment: @Elliot by not using floating point. See the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig. Doh! I'm looking at the program where the first thing I did was replace 'cin>>a' with 'a = 40000000001;'.

Answer (score 2):

Use double instead of int , input value exceeded int max value .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a;
    cin >> a;
    double b = sqrt(a);
    cout << b << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fixed`, it make dipsplay unbrokenly.

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <cmath>
   using namespace std;

    int main(void)
    {
        double a = 40000000001;
        cout << fixed << a << "\n";
        double b = (double )sqrt(a);
        cout << fixed <<b << "\n";
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I am not too sure if there is any such thing like long float.

Comment: `long float` is not a standard type, I guess you mean `long double` (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types )

Comment: @AndreHolzner, If the answer only for this question, double is OK

Comment: A `double` can't store the exact result, but can store an approximation ( `200000.00000249998993240296840667724609375` for me), more digits of which can be seen with `#include <iomanip>` and `setprecision(35)` or whatever value is desired.